# Don't allow form submit when error occurs

Tags: php, jquery, form-submit

I have simple reg form:

```
<div id="regform">
<form id="regform2" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table style="width:auto; min-width:80%; max-width:95%; margin:auto; border: 1px solid #29CF81;">
<tr><td colspan=3 style="background-color: #29CF81; text-align:center; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff;">Základné informácie</td>
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Meno: <td><input type="text" name="firstname" size=30 />
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Priezvisko: <td><input type="text" name="lastname" size=30 />
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Nick: <td><input type="text" name="username" size=30 required/><font color=red><sup>*</sup></font>
<tr class='info' id='username' style='display:none;'><td><td><td><div class='infoBubble top'>Zvoľte nick s dĺžkou medzi 3 - 16 znakov</div>
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;E-mailová adresa: <td><input type="text" name="email1" size=30 required/><font color=red><sup>*</sup></font>
<tr class='info' id='email1' style='display:none;'><td><td><td><div class='infoBubble top'>Neplatná e-mailová adresa</div>
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Potvrdiť e-mail: <td><input type="text" name="email2" size=30 required/><font color=red><sup>*</sup></font>
<tr class='info' id='email2' style='display:none;'><td><td><td><div class='infoBubble top'>Zadané e-mailové adresy sa nezhodujú</div>
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Heslo: <td><input type="password" name="password1" size=30 required/><font color=red><sup>*</sup></font>
<tr class='info' id='password1' style='display:none;'><td><td><td><div id='passwordText' class='infoBubble top'></div>
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Potvrdiť heslo: <td><input type="password" name="password2" size=30 required/><font color=red><sup>*</sup></font>
<tr class='info' id='password2' style='display:none;'><td><td><td><div id='passwordText' class='infoBubble top'>Zadané heslá sa nezhodujú</div>
<tr><td colspan=3 style="background-color: #29CF81; text-align:center; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff;">Osobné informácie</td>
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Avatar: <td><input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" />
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Vek: <td><input type="text" name="age" size=30 />
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Trieda: <td><select size=1 name="class" /><option value="" selected><option value="prima">Príma<option value="sekunda">Sekunda<option value="tercia">Tercia<option value="kvarta">Kvarta<option value="kvinta">Kvinta<option value="septima">Septima<option value="oktava">Oktáva<option value="1b">1.B<option value="1c">1.C<option value="1d">1.D<option value="2b">2.B<option value="2c">2.C<option value="2d">2.D<option value="3b">3.B<option value="3c">3.C<option value="3d">3.D<option value="4b">4.B<option value="4c">4.C<option value="profesor">Profesor/ka<option value="exGamca">exGAMČA</select>
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;Pohlavie: <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="muz"/>Muž<input type="radio" name="gender" value="zena"/>Žena
<tr><td><td>&nbsp;O mne: <td><textarea type="text" name="about" rows=5 cols=40 style="resize: none;"></textarea>
<tr><td><td><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" style="height:35px;width:120px;margin-right:5px" value="Registrovať" /><input class="button" style="height:35px;" type="reset" name="reset" value="Zmazať" />
<tr><td><td style="font-size:12px; color:gray;">&nbsp;Poznámka: Polia označené "<font color="red" size="4px">*</font>" sú povinné.
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Then I have few jQuery scripts to check if e-mail/username/password etc. are valid. For each input exists one variable with name like errorEmail, which has value 1 if there is error, or value 0 when it's okay:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function() {



$('input[name="email1"]').keyup(function() {

var valueEmail1 = $(this).val();
var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
var valueLength = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
if (valueLength > 0) {
if (emailRegex.test(valueEmail1)) {
$('#email1').css('display', 'none');
var errorEmail1 = 0;
}
else {
$('#email1').css('display', 'table-row');
var errorEmail1 = 1;
}

}

else {
$('#email1').css('display', 'none');
var errorEmail1 = 0;
}

});

$('input[name="email2"]').keyup(function() {

var valueEmail2 = $(this).val();
var valueLength2 = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
var valueEmail1 = $('input[name="email1"]').val();
if (valueLength2 > 0) {
if (valueEmail2 == valueEmail1) {
$('#email2').css('display', 'none');
var errorEmail2 = 0;
}       
else {
$('#email2').css('display', 'table-row');
var errorEmail2 = 1;
}

}

else {
$('#email2').css('display', 'none');
var errorEmail2 = 0;
}

}); 

$('input[name="username"]').keyup(function() {

var valueUsername = $(this).val();
var valueLength3 = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
if (valueLength3 > 0) {
if (valueLength3 >= 3 && valueLength3 <= 16 ) {
$('#username').css('display', 'none');
var errorUsername = 0;
}       
else {
$('#username').css('display', 'table-row');
var errorUsername = 1;
}

}

else {
$('#username').css('display', 'none');
var errorUsername = 0;
}

}); 

$('input[name="password1"]').keyup(function() {

var valuePassword1 = $(this).val();
var passwordRegex = /^([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[/]|[.])+([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[/]|[.])+([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[/]|[.])$/;
var valueLength4 = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
if (valueLength4 > 0) {

if (valueLength4 >= 6 && valueLength4 <= 18) {
if (passwordRegex.test(valuePassword1)) {
$('#password1').css('display', 'none');
var errorPassword1 = 0;
}
else {
$('#password1').css('display', 'table-row');
$('#passwordText').html('Vaše heslo obsahuje nepovolené znaky');
var errorPassword1 = 1;
}

}

else {
$('#password1').css('display', 'table-row');
$('#passwordText').html('Heslo musí byť v rozmedzí 6-18 znakov');
var errorPassword1 = 1;
}

}

else {
$('#password1').css('display', 'none');
var errorPassword1 = 0;
}

});     

$('input[name="password2"]').keyup(function() {

var valuePassword2 = $(this).val();
var valueLength5 = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
var valuePassword1 = $('input[name="password1"]').val();
if (valueLength5 > 0) {
if (valuePassword2 == valuePassword1) {
$('#password2').css('display', 'none');
var errorPassword2 = 0;
}       
else {
$('#password2').css('display', 'table-row');
var errorPassword2 = 1;
}

}

else {
$('#password2').css('display', 'none');
var errorPassword2 = 0;
}

});         


$('#regform2').submit(function(event) {
if(errorUsername == 1 || errorEmail1 == 1 || errorEmail2 == 1 || errorPassword1 == 1) {
event.preventDefault();
}

});



});

</script>
```

At the end I have following (not working):

```
$('#regform2').submit(function(event) {
if(errorUsername == 1 || errorEmail1 == 1 || errorEmail2 == 1 || errorPassword1 == 1) {
event.preventDefault();
}

});
```

And finally, php code to update database when everything is okay (working):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //database update etc.
}
```

What I want is, that when there is one (or more) errors in the form, it alerts the error(s) and stop submiting form, so php code isn't executed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use jquery validate plugin

Comment: clearly those variables do not contain what you seem to think they do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#regform2').submit(function(e) {
   if(errorUsername == 1 || errorEmail1 == 1 || errorEmail2 == 1 || errorPassword1 == 1) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```

is what you want.
also its documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: if return false is not working i don't think so PreventDefault will work.

Comment: return false just returns from there

Comment: return false will not work. since it only does the work of break. 
we need here to prevent the default behaviour of submit button. thats what preventDefault() does.

Comment: @jahanviKashyap - Break what, there's nothing to break ?

Comment: I tried to remove whole condition and leave only preventDefault(), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Share all your form and jquery functions about this form to find your problem.

Comment: `return false` is dangerous because it also prevents event propagation... if `e.preventDefault()` is all your need, use it.

Comment: @Terry my bad, I forgot to update that part. I already tried preventDefault but it didn't work.

Comment: UPDATE: I just found out, thatthe  whole problem was in one stupid bracket, so the preventDefault actually IS working. However, the condition is still wrong, but I think I can solve it. Thanks for your time and sorry.

Comment: Your error variables (like errorEmail1 ) are local. So your submit function does not work. Also your controller functions have some wrongs, fix it and your controller functions are triggered when keyup, it is not true method. You should make them to work when user click submit button. Other way is not true.